# pycharm Terminal instance not using activated project's venv

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

my pycharm terminal wont print installed modules of the activated env, but rather the default  python environment. below is a picture of what I mean
[image]

on the left is the output of pip list whiles on the right is the correct modules in the environment, can anyone tell me what am doing wrong, but my code use the correct environment but the terminal seems to mess up. am using win 11 here.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is caused by your `Path` not being set correctly when the virtual environment is activated. Either the additional entry for the venv isn't added, or is added after existing entries. This means that when the shell looks for an executable that matches `pip`, it finds the system version first and uses it.

Check the output of `pip --version` to see which one it is. If it's not the one in your venv, check the output of `$env:Path -split ";"`. If set correctly, the scripts directory in your virtual environment should be the first entry in the list.

If that's the case, solving why is a bit more complicated and would require more details. I would recommend double checking the various settings for terminal integration are set correctly in PyCharm settings, and try activating the venv manually in an external terminal, then activating the venv manually in the terminal in PyCharm.